# send canvas image as pdf file directly on button click via email

Tags: php, jquery, html, canvas, html-email

by using the below jquery code, I could able to download the canvas image as pdf.

```
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function () {

        html2canvas(jQuery("#abc"), {
            onrendered: function(canvas) {
                theCanvas = canvas;
                document.body.appendChild(canvas);

                // Convert and download as image 
                Canvas2Image.saveAsPNG(canvas); 
                jQuery("#img-out").append(canvas);
                // Clean up 
                //document.body.removeChild(canvas);
            }
        });

}); 

</script>


<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
jQuery('#btnSave').click(function() {       
        html2canvas(jQuery("canvas"), {
            onrendered: function(canvas) {         
                var imgData = canvas.toDataURL(
                    'image/png');              
                var doc = new jsPDF('p', 'mm');
                doc.addImage(imgData, 'PNG', 37, 10);
                doc.save('test.pdf');
            }
        });
    });
    }); 
</script>
```

But I also want to send this generated pdf file via email directly by using the below php script.

```
<?php
 $to= 'test@gmail.com' . ',';
$to .= 'testamjadm61@gmail.com';
$sub='test1';
$msg= <<<EOF
   <html>
   <body>
   Pls find the atteached pdf file.
    </body>
    </html>
EOF;
$headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";

// Additional headers
$headers .= 'From: <centos_test@example.com>' . "\r\n";
?>
```

Is it possible to attach a file by using this script?
If so, could you pls tell me how to do that?
If don't, pls tell me another alternative ways to do the same.

Pls note: I want all the php and the jquery in a single php file including the email function.

Comment: Will need to upload the image in order to attach it. It's not hard to find out how to do the upload

Comment: I'm not using databse, So, is there anyway to send the automatically generated file directly without uploading to any database?